# render link tag in react object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am mapping through my object data in `const.js` that contains a react-router `<Link>` within the object but when viewed in the browser it doesn't output it as a react link, instead it outputs it as `<link to="/">` instead of an `<a href="">`.

How can I output my object data and correctly display the `<Link>` ?

https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KkA6XGxeVPedj8apbOA

**Hello.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import frequentQuestions from './const'
import Freq from './freqQues'

export default class Hello extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
      {/* Frequently asked Questions */}
       {frequentQuestions.map(fq =>
        <div key={fq.id}>
         <Freq key={fq.id} question={fq.question} answer={fq.answer} />
        </div>
      )}
  </div>
  )
 }
}
```

**freqQues.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router'
import './styles.css'

export default class Freq extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return(
    <div >
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ {__html: this.props.answer } } />
  </div>
  )
 }
}
```

**const.js**

```
const frequentQuestions = [
  { id: 1, 
    question: 'Question1',
    answer: '<Link to="/contact">answer1</Link>' 
  },
  { id: 2,
   question: 'question2',
   answer: 'answer2, bla bla bla <br /><Link to="/blabla"> bla bla </Link> 
   <br />bla bla'
  },
  { id: 3,
    question: 'question3', 
    answer: 'answer3' 
  },
  { id: 4,
    question: 'question4', 
    answer: 'answer4' 
  },
  { id: 5, 
    question: 'question5', 
    answer: 'answer5' 
  },
]

export default frequentQuestions
```

Comment: `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` expects a JS object with `__html` property which should be valid `HTML` markup. Instead you are providing `<Link>` there and expecting it to render that component's html. React won't process `<Link>` there.`dangerouslySetInnerHTML` as name suggests should be avoided

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always try not to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML since it is more like wild innerHTML setting. React does not check for its own validations for this method.Setting HTML from code is risky because it's easy to inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack.

Instead, try modifying your code like given below.

**const.js**

```
    const frequentQuestions = [
      { id: 1, 
        question: 'Question1',
        answer: {
            to: '/contact',
            linkText: 'answer1'
        }
      },
      { id: 2,
       question: 'question2',
       answer: {
         to: '/blah',
         linkText: 'blahblah'
        }
      }

    ]
export default frequentQuestions
```

Also for your **freqQues.js**

```
// freQues.js    
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import './styles.css'

const Freq = ({question, answer})=>(
  <div >
    {question} 
    <Link to={answer.to}>{answer.linkText}</Link>
  </div>
)

export default Freq;
```

Since Link is a component of react-router-dom You have to wrap your component with the Router component

**Main.js**

```
//Main.js
import React from 'react'
import {render} from 'react-dom'
import Hello from './Hello'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom'

const RootComp = () => (
  <Router>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Hello}/>     
  </Router>
)


render(<RootComp />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

I have a working example of the above item in https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KkAz4y3H_za5ZtmeNHS

Please comment if you need more explanations.

Comment: That's great for a simplified case however i could have a link anywhere within my string e.g `lorum ipsum <Link to="#">Link</Link> Lorum Ipusum.` Some sentences may even have multiple links, and I will need to use `<br />` or an alternative method of splitting the string into newlines, how can this be handled

Comment: Instead of string splitting, you may do it in an array. 
answer: [
'String lorun ipsum',
{to: '/blah', linkText: 'sdfsdf'},
'another string'
]

Then in your freQues
use map to determine which component to render if string/object comes.

Comment: @tomharrison try something like this https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KkB2_wo4tI-T895BHe3

Comment: It's not exactly what I wanted , maybe there is a way to wrap a block of text within the string in a # for instance and replace that with the `<Link>` tags maybe? However I think I will try the way suggested by yourself as I'm not sure how to do that and I think splitting it into an array would work although not the most elegant solution

Comment: @tomharrisonYep it is not the most elegant way but you may consider it as a better way than dangerously setting inner html.